# how to show a dialog on the splashscreen using RFlutter Alert or just pop up dialog and exit if there is no wifi

Tags: flutter

Sorry, I just started learning flutter and making a simple page. I want to check if there is internet, if not I want to show the pop up alert if possible using rFlutterPackage, on the splash screen. If I can't use splashscreen I can just redirect to the new page and show only dialog.

Alert dialogue is only trigger when the button was pressed?

How can I close the application once the user clicks the alert button?

How can I use dialogue to show on top of splash screen so the user can click?

**Main page**

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:algorithm_send_location/pages/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:algorithm_send_location/pages/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:algorithm_send_location/pages/initial_warning.dart';

var routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  "/home": (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(),
};

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
    theme:
        ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.amber, accentColor: Colors.green[200]),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: _checkConnectivity ? SplashScreen() : WarningScreen(),
    routes: routes));

get _checkConnectivity async {
  var internetResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();

  if (internetResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
    return false;
  } else if (internetResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
      internetResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
    return false;
    //return true;
  }
}
```

**Alert I want to use**

```
Alert(
      context: context,
      type: AlertType.warning,
      title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
      desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          child: Text(
            "There is no internet Connection",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 179, 134, 1.0),
        ),

      ],
    ).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest instead of creating a dialog before the page which may cause you issue. Just create a full page message in your app. In that you can put code for both exit & retry. This will be more user friendly without breaking anything in app.

To check the live status of network you can use [Connectivity Package](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity)

To exit the app use

> SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');

Read about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html)